# Problems with fcgi socket via supervisor

Tags: django, sockets, nginx, fastcgi, supervisord

I run django application via supervisor.

Command: `manage.py runfcgi daemonize=false method=prefork socket=/tmp/django.sock pidfile=/tmp/django.pid`

The application runs as `django` user.

```
ls -al /tmp/django.sock
srwxr-xr-x 1 django www-data 0 2013-02-25 22:18 /tmp/django.sock
```

Nginx runs as `www-data` user.

Nginx need access for write. But it is not. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define a `umask` value, so the socket permissions are set correctly:

```
manage.py runfcgi daemonize=false method=prefork socket=/tmp/django.sock umask=002 pidfile=/tmp/django.pid
```

The default is `022`; remove writing from the group and other permissions. Switching that to `002` only removes write for other, leaving it in place for the `www-data` group.

Comment: Thanks, but umask dont work for "daemonize=false" - umask only works for "daemonize=true"